# XAMPP Database connectivity issue with Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, xampp

I had a issue with XAMPP / phpMyAdmin and got following error message,

"phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

So i searched in the google and got solution and i changed the values in the /phpmyadmin/config.inc.php like below,

From : `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` 
to : `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';`

and finally i got connected with the xampp / phpMyAdmin.

But when i access my projects inside the XAMPP and i got the db connectivity errors like below,

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

Changing the "auth_type" in phpMyAdmin from "config" to "http". Will affect db issue in Codeigniter?

Please suggest on the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your Codeigniter based application and phpMyAdmin both have separate files to connect to database.

Please edit the file:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\instagram\application\config\database.php
```

and put appropriate values on following lines:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'YOUR_HOST';
$db['default']['username'] = 'user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
```

Do not forget to first create the database, user and then given rights to that user in mysql.

Comment: Nope. I have given everything correct in Codeigniter also. I just need  solution that why it is not connecting with db if i change config to http.

Comment: phpmyadmin config has no relation with codeigniter. The error you posted is related to codeigniter, so you need to change codeigniter configuration file database.php

Answer (score -2):

Just go to `http://localhost/`:

1. Select SECURITY from left pane.
2. Set the USERNAME (by default it is set to `root`) and PASSWORD (by default it is empty).

Enter the password twice to confirm. Restart the MySQL in XAMPP.